# Remove "by [username]" in a GitHub Pages document.title

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown, page-title

I have a GitHub Pages site, and I don't want to use the raw html to develop the site yet because non developers on the team will be pushing.

The problem is that the `document.title` contains "by [username]" at the end. I want to remove that and just make it be the beginning text.

I already tried `title: [custom title]` in Jekyll and it still has the organization name at the end.

I am using the Midnight theme.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, try blanking the `title_suffix` like so: `title_suffix: ""`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: I might be thinking of an option for the paginate plugin for jekyll. My bad.

Comment: Yeah I searched it up and pagination was all that I found

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Or if you aren't using any theme, post the layouts files content

Comment: I am using the midnight theme.

Comment: Any code repository url ?

Comment: Yes, at https://github.com/thebclickteam/thebclickteam.github.io

Comment: I'm a little confused. The repo you posted doesn't seem to match the content of your site. Or more specifically, the index of the site matches the readme in your repo, not the index in your repo. Have you tried disabling the theme? Are you sure your site contains the latest changes in your repo?

Comment: Jekyll builds the readme file into an index.html themed page. So after the website is completely finalized, and not needing to be edited all the time, I will use actual the actual html generated from the site instead of the readme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As based in comments, you are using the **jekyll-midnight-theme**, copy the default layout file of the `jekyll-theme-midnight` repo into `_layouts` directory in your Jekyll website.

1. Create the `/_layouts` directory
2. Copy https://github.com/pages-themes/midnight/blob/master/_layouts/default.html into `/_layouts`

Now edit `/_layouts/default.html` and adjust the `<title>` HTML tag, in this case removing the "by " part, so this:

```
 <title>{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }} by {{ site.github.owner_name }}</title>
```

replace it with:

```
  <title>{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</title>
```

Now your website won't include the "by [organization name]" at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Now I can also clean up some of the code in the layout html file that I don't want!